# Either OData or Code-First fails: derived navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, code-first

I'm having a complex situation where I either get a problem with the Code-First portion of my project, or a problem with the OData portion of my project...

I have an abstract class `Person` of which I derive two classes `User` and `Driver`:

```cs
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(User))]
[KnownType(typeof(Driver))]
public abstract class Person
{
    [Key, DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int RelationID { get; set; }
}

public class User : Person { }
public class Driver : Person { } // shortened for sake of readability
```

Now I have a model `Relation`, which can contain both users and/or drivers.

```cs
[DataContract]
public class Relation
{
    [Key, DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, when I let Code-First generate migration code, I can see that it wants to add two columns `Relation_ID` and `Relation_ID1` in order to cope with the mapping of `Users` and `Drivers`. I applied the `[InverseProperty("ID")]` attribute to both navigation properties in order to try to solve this (as described here: [Code First DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx)). But still, the problem persists. So, this is not working.

Now, you would say: why not make it an `ICollection<Person> People` property, and use `this.db.People.OfType<User>()` in order to cast the objects to the right model and retrieve it that way. This is perfectly acceptable, but now it turns into an OData problem.

I want to be able to call `public IQueryable<User> GetUsers([FromODataUri] int key)` from the `Relations` controller in order to use `/odata/Relations(16)/Users` to get all users from a relation. If there is no `Users` property present in the `Relation` model, the OData parser rejects any such call because it can not resolve to the correct method.

So I'm stuck between the designs of both worlds. I'm guessing that in order to correctly solve this problem, the focus should lie on the Code-First part, not on the OData part. Any ideas are appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the ICollection People property as well and exclude Users and Drivers properties from the Data model. For example,

```
[DataContract]
public class Relation
{
    [Key, DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }      

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return People.OfType<User>();
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Driver> Drivers
    {
        get
        {
            return People.OfType<Driver>();
        }
    }
}
```

In your DbModelBuilder code exclude the Users and Drivers properties by doing,

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var relation = modelBuilder.Entity<Relation>();
        relation.Ignore(p => p.Users);
        relation.Ignore(p => p.Drivers);
    }
```

In your ODataModelBuilder, exclude the People property if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems like a good solution, however I have trouble implementing it. I cannot call the `OfType<T>` method on `People` inside the get context of either `Users` or `Drivers`. I tried solving this by looping over each `Person` inside the get, checking whether it is a User or Driver, adding it to a list and returning that list. But this gives a NullRef exception, saying that People is empty. I await your comment on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why you cannot call OfType<T> in Users and Drivers properties. Also, you should either have lazy loading enabled or have null checks on the People property.

Comment: Apologies for such a late response; I was on a vacation. I got a fresh look at my code and saw that I was missing a using (namely the `System.Linq`) in my `Relation` model. This was the reason why I could not call the `OfType` method, and strangely enough VS did not show a resolve on this. I've fixed it, and your solution works perfectly, thanks!